# MediaPlayer prepare() hangs on custom device

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm currently implementing streaming internet audio on a custom tablet (i.e. not Samsung, Google, etc).  I developed the code and tested on a Samsung tablet which worked fine.  When installing on the custom tablet, the `MediaPlayer` hangs on the call to `prepare()`.  I have implemented `OnPreparedListener`, `OnErrorListener`, `OnBufferingUpdateListner`, and `OnCompletionListener` all with logs for basic troubleshooting.  I am implementing the streaming in a class that extends `Service` and uses a separate thread. I have tried both `prepare()` and `prepareAsync()`.

To clarify, when I say the `MediaPlayer` *hangs*, I mean I receive NO error messages, crashes, log output, etc. The app continues to function, but `onPrepared(...)`  never gets called.

I configure the player like this:

```
private void configureMediaPlayer(String streamUrl) {
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build();
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(attributes);
    Log.d(TAG, "Media player configured");
    playTuneInStation(streamUrl);
}
```

I attempt to play the music stream like this:

```
private void playStation(String streamUrl) {
    Log.d(TAG, "playStation: " + streamUrl);
    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopped media player.");
    }
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(() -> Log.d(TAG, "Main thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId()));
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing stream on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".");
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for media player to be prepared");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO: Gracefully inform user of failure
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I implement `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` to start playing the stream:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Media player prepared.  Starting playback.");
    mp.start();
}
```

Again, this works great on the Samsung table, but, due to the nature of the project, we have to use custom tablets provided by the client.  We use `VideoView`s in some places which seem to work and play audio, but those are local files on the device (not sure if that matters).  The devices use a 4G network and all web api calls work fine so I don't think it would be anything related to network. I just find it odd that it will hang forever (I've let it sit for 30 min with no crashes, errors, logs, etc).  The app is totally responsive during this time.

I'm not sure if there is some other configuration I can use which might help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've tried loading a local audio file by replacing:

```
setDataSource(streamUrl);
```

with:

```
setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(filename));
```

and it played the audio without a problem.

**UPDATE 2**

I've now tried passing in an invalid URL to the `setDataSource(...)` method and the `OnErrorListener` is called with the error that it can't load the resource.  Also, I passed in the URL that should work, but stripped a few characters from the end. It seemed to recognize it as a potentially valid stream because it posted error logs and retried loading the resource 10 times before failing in the `OnErrorListener`.

Here are the logs I receive when `prepare()` (also tried with `prepareAsync()`) is called:

```
05-15 11:02:33.149 252-26756/? D/FslExtractor: FslExtractor::FslExtractor mime=audio/mpeg
05-15 11:02:33.150 252-26756/? D/FslExtractor: FslExtractor::Init BEGIN
GetLibraryName lib_mp3_parser_arm11_elinux.3.0.so
load parser name lib_mp3_parser_arm11_elinux.3.0.so
FslExtractor::CreateParserInterface success
05-15 11:02:33.150 252-26756/? I/FslExtractor: Core parser MP3PARSER_03.01.15  build on Nov 17 2016 13:55:34 
05-15 11:02:33.150 252-26756/? D/FslExtractor: createParser2 flag=5e,err=0
05-15 11:02:33.150 252-26756/? I/FslExtractor: mReadMode=0,mNumTracks=1
bSeekable 1
05-15 11:02:33.150 252-26756/? D/FslExtractor: FslExtractor::ParseMediaFormat BEGIN
ParseAudio index=0,type=5,subtype=2829696637
```

It looks in these logs like it's beginning to parse the audio, but nothing happens afterward.

Comment: should it not be `mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();`? This will then callback to the `OnPreparedListener`

Comment: Mark is correct that you should call `prepareAsync()` for network media. Also, do you have any information about what the tablet manufacturer might have done to the underlying framework code? Or is it assumed to be stock Android and you are in the dark?

Comment: @Mark Keen Both `prepare()` and `prepareAsync()` should hit the callback to the `OnPreparedListener`
@Dave I've created my own thread dedicated to playing media in the service I'm running and `prepare()` is being called in this thread. The docs recommend calling `prepareAsync()` in order to not block, but this isn't an issue the way I've set it up.
Unfortunately we're not sure of any modifications to the underlying framework, but audio plays in the `VideoView`s we have in the project.

Comment: I know this is a tough one to answer due to the unknowns and especially considering that this all works on a standard Samsung tablet.  I don't really see any further settings for the `MediaPlayer` that I can use to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since there were no crashes or decent logs that pointed to anything, I switched to using Google's `ExoPlayer`, which seems to be working just fine.

```
private void configureMediaPlayer(String streamUrl) {
    Log.d(TAG, "configureMediaPlayer: " + streamUrl);
    DefaultBandwidthMeter meter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    mMediaPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,
            new DefaultTrackSelector(
                    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(
                            meter)));
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "appName"), meter);
    mMediaSourceFactory = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);
    mMediaPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    MediaSource mediaSource = mMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(streamUrl));
    Log.d(TAG, "playTuneInStation: media source set");
    mMediaPlayer.addListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
}
```

If anybody has any ideas of why the original idea using `MediaPlayer` didn't work, please feel free to comment or post another answer.  Thanks.